# How can I create a project in the Git repository root using Eclipse EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, eclipse-oxygen, new-project

I would like to add the project files of a brand-new Eclipse project to the root-level of a git repo.  I would like it to look like something like this:

```
./projectrepo/.git
./projectrepo/.project
./projectrepo/src
...
```

However, the Eclipse Egit wizard provides no obvious way to do that, and insists on creating an undesired subdirectory (screenshots below):

```
./projectrepo/project/.git
./projectrepo/project/.project
./projectrepo/project/src
...
```

How can I get Eclipse to add my files at the repository root?

I understand that the Egit manual advises against this, but I do not plan to ever have multiple projects in this repository, so the extra directory is unnecessary (and counts against filesystem path limits on Windows).  The fact that it's advised against tells me it must be possible somehow (or the documentation's wrong).

---

System information:

Windows 7 64-bit

Eclipse Oxygen Java EE (4.7.0 Build id: 20170620-1800)

Eclipse EGit 4.8.0.201706111038-r

---

**Screenshots of Eclipse's current undesired behavior**

Configure Git Repository wizard.  Most of the things I'd like to change, like `Target Location`, are uneditable.  `Path within repository` can only be used to add more extra folders.  `Use or create repository in parent folder of project` has a freetext repository path input, but only parent folders will validate and can be used. 
[image: Configure Git Repository wizard screenshot]

Resulting undesired Git repository structure.  I would like my project files to be in this directory, not an extra "TestProject" folder:
[image: Git repository directory structure, with undesired subdirectory]

Comment: That little tick box “use or create repository in parent folder of project” looks promising. What does it do?

Comment: I described it next to one of my screenshots.  It's seems to be used to create the git repo inside the eclipse workspace.  However, I do want to follow the other EGit recommendation and keep the git repo separate from the Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead to:

- [import your project into your Eclipse workspace](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm)
- then use Team/Share project: it should detect the Git repo in it.

That way, you should avoid the double-folder creation.